# How do I profile a single SP with SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I'm trying to evaluate the relative performance of using a `WHERE... IN` clause in my SP vs `UNION`s.

I've tried looking at the execution time and using `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` but everything just comes back as taking 0ms all the time.

So I'm trying to use SQL Server Profiler. I selected the `TSQL_SPs` template but even before I run the SP the trace is filling up with garbage. How do I tell it to only capture relevant data for a specific SP?

Comment: Have you pulled a plan for that statement yet? It may have all the answers. It is possible that your `in` optimizes into a `union` anyway, but you'll only know from the actual plan. I never used the pre-defined profiles and always set up my own filters using host/login/user credentials, database name and/or application name if populated. See if that helps. And I do not think that your question deserves a downvote!

Comment: @ajeh Setting up a filter on the DB name cleaned things up, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't help me evaluate the SP. The start and finish times are identical.

Comment: Do you mean it executes in less than 1 millisecond? That is possible. At this point I would run that isolated statement coded using `in` and `union` and compare the plans. Tracing is probably not the right vehicle for your investigation.

Comment: @ajeh Good to know. I've run both SPs with "Show actual execution plan" selected. I'm not a DBA though and after reviewing both plans nothing stands out to me as being better than the other. Could be I'm just not interpreting things correctly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sql profiler, when you are creating a new trace, you can change the trace properties. Click on Events selection tab in trace properties and go to column filters.

Then in textData, click on Like and add some unique word from your SP that you need and then run the trace. This way your trace will give you data of your SP. 
You can play around with column filters according to your need.